# ignore_dup_key = on in SQL Server does not ignore duplicates in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I want to create this index on the 'age' column where 2 NULLs exist

```
create unique nonclustered index idx_ncl_forindexes_age on forindexes (age)
with(drop_existing=on, **ignore_dup_key=on**)
```

which means values are not unique. But I want to ignore that fact and create unique index for future records. While writing 'ignore_dup_key=on' I still get an error

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.forindexes' and the index name 'idx_ncl_forindexes_age'. The duplicate key value is ().
>   The statement has been terminated.

Why while using ignore_dup_key I still get this error?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If your intention is to only ignore null values which result in dups, change to a filtered index (e.g. `WHERE age IS NOT NULL`) instead of `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`. That will allow you to rebuild the existing index with existing duplicate NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`create index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments):

> Arguments
>
> UNIQUE
>
> Creates a unique index on a table or view. A unique index is
>   one in which no two rows are permitted to have the same index key
>   value. A clustered index on a view must be unique.
>
> The Database Engine does not allow creating a unique index on columns
>   that already include duplicate values, whether or not IGNORE_DUP_KEY
>   is set to ON. If this is tried, the Database Engine displays an error
>   message.